# Design a ContextMenu with a TreeView functionality

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, javafx-8, contextmenu

I want to design a `ContextMenu` with a `TreeView` functionality. I didnt found anything how can be done. I want to design a custom `TableMenu` (that button at the end of table header which can show hide the columns), using a treeView structure in ContextMenu, so the user can show/hide a group of columns, like 1-3, 4-6, and so on, or any kind of grouping, but still keeping the one by one show/hiding. The best way would be a tree structure, so if the user hides the parent all of its children are hidden and vice-versa.

Is there any possibility to adapt somehow the `TreeView` into `ContextMenu`?

I would like something like this with `CheckBox`es for instance:
[image]

Each parent node would be an item that represents a group of columns, and each child would be a column.

**P.S.**

- I know how to create and add a custom `ContextMenu` as tableMenu (I have got it from here : https://gist.github.com/Roland09/d92829cdf5e5fee6fee9) , I'm interested in how to set a tree structure to context menu instead of the list structure.
- I also know that I can add the parent like a "simple" item to the context menu, then handle as a parent, but then I Have to implement every functionality of a `TreeItem`, but I prefer a much simpler way if it exists.

Comment: Don't you just want nested menus? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I don't really know what do you mean on nested menus? If something like this : http://java-buddy.blogspot.ro/2012/02/javafx-20-add-submenu.html?m=1 then no, i want a tree structure instead of the list structure.

Comment: @James_D do you have any idea how can be done?

Comment: The image you linked shows a tree structure though. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, but that image is just a mock for that I want to do, just t o show you want I mean. It is not from a JavaFx app. Just a random treestructure image.

Comment: No, the image you linked with the menus, in your comment, has a tree structure (menus inside menus inside menus). It's generated by the code below the image.

Comment: Yes I know, but as I said I don't want something like a nested menu structure, because then I cannot see all time the children, just when I open a specific parent. I want to be able to expand/collapse the parents. I want something like `CheckTreeView` in **ControlFX** but added to a ContextMenu. Like if I could say: contextMenu.setContent(myCheckTreeView). Then If I select a parent all of the children became selected, and so on. Do you know what I mean?